# Gif blinking in RecyclerView using Fresco

Tags: android-recyclerview, gif, fresco

I use Fresco to load gif in a Recyclerview.

Here is my kotlin code:

```
fun loadResizeImage(uri: Uri, view: SimpleDraweeView, width: Int, height: Int) {
    val request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
            .setResizeOptions(ResizeOptions(width, height)).build()

val controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setOldController(view.controller)
        .setImageRequest(request)
        .build()
view.controller = controller
```

I don't play the gif, I just load it as a static image. But when I invoke `notifydatasetchanged`, the gif blinks.
I have set the `supportsChangeAnimations` to false, and only the gif is blinking. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you are resettting a controller.Can you avoid doing that if the controller uri has not changed?that should prevent the blinking.

Comment: i can set the uri as a tag to the view.if the tag equals to the uri,i just don't do the things in the block?

Comment: i have tried this, but it doesn't work well.when i invoke notifydatasetchange, i find the tag is different from the uri

Comment: Sorry.I just understood your sitaution.So notifyDatasetChanged triggers a complete redraw.Irrespective of the items being drawn previously or not.This will bring a flash in the sceen.Which will occur even for normal images loaded using fresco(not necessarily gifs),So using notifyItemChanged would be a better solution

Comment: That's right.I've done it and it works well.notifyDataSetChanged will invoke onCreateVIewHolder() which will create new views and the tag i set to the view is gone.But notifyItemChanged will retain the item of this position's identity  so the tag is not cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to set tag to the view, if the tag equals to the uri i won't reload the image. But I find when i invoke notifyDataSetChange, the tag i set to the view is changed.but when I invoke notifyItemChanged,it doesn't.I have no idea why the tag changed(i didn't scroll the RecyclerView).

Comment: r u fixed.?? Me too facing same issue.. How to set tag..?? help me